# delphi and the displaying of a listbox items

Tags: delphi, listbox

I'm using a listbox to display a simple list of filenames. I also have an edit component that allows me to search those items via a simple:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
const
  indexStart = -1;
var
  search : array[0..256] of Char;
begin
  if edit1.Text='' then exit;
  StrPCopy(search, Edit1.Text) ;
  ListBox1.ItemIndex := ListBox1.Perform(LB_SELECTSTRING, indexStart, LongInt(@search));
end;
```

Now, is there a way to "selectively" display items on a listbox? What I mean is that If I search for the an item that starts with "hello" then ONLY those that will hello will be displayed, either dimming those than don't or making visible := false altogether.
Is there a way to perform this with a listbox?

thanks!

Oh, it's Delphi 7...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always do like this (and I do it quite often):

I have an `array of string` or a `TStringList` containing the list-box items. Then, in `Edit1Change` I clear the Items property and add only those strings that match the text in the edit box.

## Array of string

If you work with an array of strings, such as

```
var
  arr: array of string;
```

that is initialized somehow, as in

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(arr, 3);
  arr[0] := 'cat';
  arr[1] := 'dog';
  arr[2] := 'horse';
end;
```

then you can do

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;
  if length(Edit1.Text) = 0 then
    for i := 0 to high(arr) do
      ListBox1.Items.Add(arr[i])
  else
    for i := 0 to high(arr) do
      if Pos(Edit1.Text, arr[i]) > 0 then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(arr[i]);
  ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

This will only display those strings in the array that *contain* `Edit1.Text`; the string need not *start* with `Edit1.Text`. To accomplish this, replace

```
Pos(Edit1.Text, arr[i]) > 0
```

with

```
Pos(Edit1.Text, arr[i]) = 1
```

## TStringList

In case of a `TStringList`, as in

```
var
  arr: TStringList;
```

and

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  arr := TStringList.Create;
  arr.Add('cat');
  arr.Add('dog');
  arr.Add('horse');
end;
```

you can do

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;
  if length(Edit1.Text) = 0 then
    ListBox1.Items.AddStrings(arr)
  else
    for i := 0 to arr.Count - 1 do
      if Pos(Edit1.Text, arr[i]) = 1 then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(arr[i]);
  ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

## Case sensitivity

The above code uses case-sensitive matching, so that "bo" will not match "Boston", for instance. To make the code not sensitive to the case, write

```
if Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Edit1.Text), AnsiLowerCase(arr[i])) > 0 then
```

instead of

```
if Pos(Edit1.Text, arr[i]) > 0 then
```

Comment: that might work. the problem I see is that I don't know how many items there are in listbox. it's not fixed. it'll be hard to set the size of the array with SetLength. unless... can I use SetLength later to reset the length of the array? or it's better to use a TStringList?

Comment: Most people always work with the `TStringList`, but personally I want to do everything manually, so I always work with `array of string`. You can change the length of a dynamic array at any time by means of `SetLength`. If you increase the length, the old items will still be there.

Comment: hmmm. i am trying with a tliststring. When I tried searching ALL the items disappear.
Oh my bad, i was loading it wrong... however it's not working. I have a 2 files called: book 1 and book 2. when I search book it find the "bo" of a file called " places in boston" but that's it

Comment: got it, i just added Lowercase() to Pos(Lowercase(Edit1.Text), Lowercase(arr[i])) to make it case insensitive.

thanks!

Comment: @Uri: Yes, I thought that was the problem, so I even updated my answer!

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for can be implemented by hooking up the standard Win32 API [IAutoComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776884(VS.85).aspx) interface to a standard TEdit, no TListBox needed.  It is not too difficult to hook up a TStrings object to IAutoComplete so it knows what strings are available for searching.